# PHP not adding to database anymore

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I currently have some code that allows me to register users into my database. I tried adding two more sections and that is their countrycode and their zipcode.

For some reason, once I added that in, the accounts are no longer being registered. I've spent a solid hour tinkering with this and trying to figure out what I've done wrong.

**Can anyone see an issue in the new code I wrote?**

My code new is on the Left, the old code is on the Right [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go on a limb here and think that either zipcode or country can't be null so your $stmt is actually coming back false.

rewrite your code like the following as it'll be much easier to deal with the problems.

```
if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 15) {
    echo ....
} elseif (strlen($username) < 5 || strlen($username) > 25) {
    echo ...
}

$stmt = ....;

if ($stmt === false) {
    throw new \Exception($mysqli->error);
}

$dw_pw = ....
```

Comment: Good attempt, but why do you say that zipcode or country would be null?

Comment: if that's all that changed then that's the only thing it can be. Needless to say if you get the error like I've shown you above it will tell you immediately what the problem is.

Comment: I've trying `$countrycode = "us"` before just to see if it would work and it didn't. I'm changing my code right now

Comment: you're just removing the last elseif and assigning the variable. then you're checking to see if that variable is false and if it is you get the error ... otherwise you're continuing on your merry way. It's not a big change to your code.

Comment: Oh woops, Sorry for not being clearer. I meant, where would I even see the error that it gives out

Comment: your code will immediately stop executing and you will see a stack trace, unless you aren't displaying errors in which case it will appear in your error_log only. alternatively you can change `throw new \Exception($mysqli->error);` to `echo $mysql->error; exit;` to achieve a similar effect. However my preference is to use exceptions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76695/discussion-between-pshyoulost-and-augwa).

Comment: I went ahead and updated my code but I do not believe I'm getting an errors http://pastebin.com/genW81cQ